# Binding Adapter not working properly

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I have a hard time making `@BindingAdapter` to work in my project.

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
public static void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
    Log.d("TEST","URL: " + url);
}
```

Above code shows how it is implemented in my ViewModel. Nothing special.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_container"
        app:imageUrl="@{item.imageUrl}"
        tools:src="@drawable/placeholder_image"/>
```

This does not work. namespace app is unbound. So what am i missing. I tried following 
https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-custom-setters-55a25a7aea47#.6ygaiwooh
and see how they set bindingAdapter. But there is something i have missed

Comment: Did you add the namespace in your layout tag along with the `xmlns:android`? If not, you should also add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Comment: "Invalidate and Restart" can be work.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same problem, I missed to bind layout using:

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity, layoutResId);
```

Comment: tnx man i use this and work for me too DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.invite_dialog, null, false);

Comment: @Swapnil: Would you please answer similar ques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70756604/flow-is-not-working-with-binding-adapters

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to use **"bind"** namespace for bindable attributes and use same names for adapter parameter and layout attribute.

#### Adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
public static void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
     Log.d("TEST","URL: " + imageUrl);
}
```

#### Layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@id/profile_container"

    bind:imageUrl="@{item.imageUrl}"

    tools:src="@drawable/placeholder_image"/>
```

where namespace **"app"** was replaced to **"bind"**. On your Layout root:

```
 xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: Could you please provide details/documentation why this makes any difference?

Comment: @Mishka this suggestion is for readability only. With the `bind` namespace, you can easily recognize the attributes of a binding adapter.

Answer (score 5):

Remember to add the following line to your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and check @BindingAdapter syntax:

```
@BindingAdapter("visibleOnScreen")
fun View.setVisibility(isVisible: ObservableBoolean) {
    if (isVisible.get())
        this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    else
        this.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

in view's xml:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:visibleOnScreen="@{viewModel.errorOccurred}" />
```

viewModel:

```
var errorOccurred = androidx.databinding.ObservableBoolean(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and none of the other solutions worked for me. Then this worked.

In activity

```
dataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your app's build.Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and enable data-binding in the android block in the app's build.Gradle file:

```
android {
.
.
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
.
.
}
```

create BindingAdapters.kt file and add @BindingAdapter with below syntax:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
  fun ImageView.bindImage(imgUrl: String){
  Glide.with(context)
  .load(imgUrl)
  .into(this)
  }
```

in view's xml use imageUrl='@{"YourImageUrl"}' syntax in the ImageView:

```
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView3"
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:background="@drawable/img"
 imageUrl='@{"YourImageUrl"}'/>
```

This works well ;)

My project Gradle version: 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I just placed buildFeatures block after compileOptions and kotlinOptions in android block of build.gradle(:app). It worked

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
 databinding true
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are using `app:imageUrl="@{item.imageUrl}"` in the xml, make sure you have a String called `imageUrl` in your model.

You must pass the url link of the image and not the binderAdapter's name.

Syntax :

```
app:BinderAdapterName="@{item.imagelink}"
```