# Android Data Binding - Using BindingAdapter with the "android" namespace does not work

Tags: android, android-binding-adapter

In Android's [data binding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#custom_setters), it says that

> You can also write adapters for android namespace.

I followed the sample code in that documentation and tried to bind to TextView's `android:text` setter.

This is the BinderAdapter I wrote:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setText(TextView view, CharSequence text) {
    view.setText(text + " - the BinderAdapter works!");
    Log.d("MY_TAG", "the BinderAdapter works!");
}
```

and this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is dummy text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the app I expect to see the text "This is dummy text - the BinderAdapter works!", however, the text I see is "This is dummy text". Moreover, looking at the logs I don't see the `setText()` being called.

I read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533341/binding-adapter-not-working-properly)) suggestions for using a namespace other than "android", however, it is important to me that I will not need to pay special attention and place different namespaces throughout my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, you did not use a binding expression. The data binding framework only evaluates attributes in which you use a binding expression. Second, there already is a binding adapter for `android:text`, and I am not certain what happens if the data binding framework encounters more than one binding adapter for the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. I initially thought that setting dataBinding { enabled = true } in the app's build.gradle file was enough to have my views go through BindingAdapter methods, but I understand now that it is not the case. In addition to the binding expression (for example @{@string/test_string}) it seems I also needed to surround my layout with a '<layout ...>...</layout>' tags + use DataBindingUtil.setContentView(...) for it to work. One last thing, what do you mean by "Second, there already is a binding adapter for android:text"?

Comment: "what do you mean by "Second, there already is a binding adapter for android:text"?" -- I mean exactly what it says. You do not have to write one. The data binding framework already has one. Quoting the page that you linked to: "The android attributes have already had BindingAdapters created."

Comment: If this is true (which seems to be the case) then the documentation on `BindingAdapter` is also wrong https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html =(