# Flow is not working with Binding Adapters

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

For a particular Recycler View Item, If I select the `Checkbox` (tick it) then I need the text of its corresponding `TextView` to formatted as *Strikethrough*.

I am using Binding Adapters, Flow and Live Data.
But after selecting the checkbox, its corresponding `TextView` is not getting formatted.

But If I navigate to some other fragment and come back to here(FruitFragmnet) then the TextView data is formatted. (i.e. the database gets updated correctly on ticking checkbox but the live data emission is delayed to UI)

**Possible Root Cause**: My update to Room Database is happening immeialtey, but from database the `LiveData` is not flown to UI immediately.

I did lot of trial and errors, read multiple similar questions but I was unable to find the missing link and solution to this issue.

Please advice. Following is the code:

**BindingAdapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("markAsCompleted")
fun markAsCompleted(textView: TextView, completed: Boolean) {
    if (completed) {
        textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
    } else {
        textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
    }
}
@BindingAdapter("setItems")
fun setItems(view: RecyclerView, items: List<Fruit>?) {
    items?.let {
        (view.adapter as SettingAdapter).submitList(items)
    }
}
```

**Fruit Fragment with Recycler View**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="settingViewModel"
        type="com.example.ui.SettingViewModel" />
</data>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fruits_list"
            setItems="@{settingViewModel.allList}" // This is Binding Adapter
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
</layout>
```

**Above Fruit's Fragment Item View**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <import type="android.widget.CompoundButton" />
        <variable
            name="fruit"
            type="com.example.data.Fruit" />
        <variable
            name="settingViewModel"
            type="com.example.ui.SettingViewModel" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
         ...
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fruit_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="@{fruit.completed}"
            android:onClick="@{(view) -> settingViewModel.completeFruit(fruit,((CompoundButton)view).isChecked())}"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fruit_name"
            markAsCompleted="@{fruit.completed}" // This is Binding Adapter
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{fruit.fruit}" />
          ....
```

**Fruit Fragment**

```
class FruitFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentFruitBinding
    private lateinit var fruitAdapter: FruitAdapter
    private val viewModel: SettingViewModel by activityViewModels()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentFruitBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false).apply {
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
            settingViewModel = viewModel
        }
        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        fruitAdapter = FruitAdapter(viewModel)
        binding.fruitslist.apply {
            adapter = fruitAdapter
        }
    }
}
```

**SettingViewModel**

```
class SettingViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val app = getApplication<Application>()
    private val dao = Database.getDatabase(app.applicationContext).dao

    val allList: LiveData<List<Fruit>> = dao.getFruits().asLiveData().distinctUntilChanged()

    fun completeFruit(fruit: Fruit, completed: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (completed) {
                dao.updateCompleted(fruit.id, completed)
            } else {
                dao.updateCompleted(fruit.id, completed)
            }
        }
    }
  ....  
}
```

**DAO Class**

```
@Dao
interface DatabaseDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM fruit_table")
    fun getFruits(): Flow<List<Fruit>>

    @Query("UPDATE fruit_table SET completed = :completed WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun updateCompleted(id: Int, completed: Boolean)
    }
```

**Recycler View Adapter**

```
class FruitAdapter(private val viewModel: SettingViewModel) : ListAdapter<Fruit, ViewHolder>(FruitDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item, viewModel)
    }

    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ContainerFruitBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: Fruit, viewModel: SettingViewModel) {
            binding.apply {
                settingViewModel = viewModel
                fruit = item
                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ContainerFruitBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}

class FruitDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Fruit>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Fruit, newItem: Fruit): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Fruit, newItem: Fruit): Boolean {
        return oldItem.fruit == newItem.fruit
    }
}
```

**Data Class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "fruit_table")
data class Fruit(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var fruit: String,
    var completed: Boolean = false
)
```

Comment: I think your issue is in diff util callback.. during `areContentsTheSame` method, instead of comparing only fruit.. try comparing entire objects like oldItem == newItem. I think that’ll resolve your issue.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change the second parameter of `setItems` function to `LiveData` in `BindingAdapter`:

```
@BindingAdapter("setItems")
fun setItems(view: RecyclerView, data: LiveData<List<Fruit>>) {
    data.value?.let {
        (view.adapter as SettingAdapter).submitList(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I tried your suggestion but it didn't worked.
When I click on the checkbox nothing happens. If I navigate to some other screen and then comeback to this screen then the TextView text is formatted correctly as strikethrough